# Using PHP within XSL

Tags: php, xslt, document

Is it possible to use PHP within an XSL document?

Always when I try to do so I get errors... so before freaking out I'd like to know whether or not it's even possible. (I am an absolute beginner)

I have an XSL file like this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>

   <style type="text/css">
    [...]
   </style>

 </head>
 <body>

[...]

  <div id="content">
   <?php echo $anything; ?>
  </div>

[...]

 </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(I cut the code)

So I am including the XML file via PHP (that XML file is styled with this XSL file)
And now I tried to echo the content of for example $anything

But it doesn't work

Comment: Please specify, how do you try it.

Comment: Which errors? What are you trying to do exactly, and why in this way over another?

Answer (score 2):

If you'll use the XSLTProcessor class to do your XSL, you can just [registerPHPFunctions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php).  I do it all the time for certain data manipulations within the XSL.  Then I can call any PHP function or method I want in the XSL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in both the xsl an the xml it is transforming.

- Your server must parse .xsl/.xml files as php
- Your php must generate valid xsl/xml

Comment: How is it used in the XML being transformed?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running [Saxon-EE 9.7](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) XSLT processor, then you can use the [`<xsl:processing-instruction name="php">`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_processing-instruction.asp) as your `<?php` tag with one quirky caveat: you have to add the `?` immediately before the closing `</xsl:processing-instruction>` tag.

```
<xsl:processing-instruction name="php">
    echo "hello world!";
?</xsl:processing-instruction>
```

To use your example, it would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>

   <style type="text/css">
    [...]
   </style>

 </head>
 <body>

[...]

  <div id="content">

        <xsl:processing-instruction name="php">
            echo $anything;
        ?</xsl:processing-instruction>

  </div>

[...]

 </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simplexml to manipulate the XML in PHP. http://nl.php.net/simplexml there's the reference of the simplexml class. So after you load the XML file into PHP and before echoing it using the asXML()-function, you can alter the XML through the simplexml interface.